# subprocess.call throwing [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to execute a Rscript from my python program via subprocess.call method. However, python kept throwing the following message:

`[WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect`

Ive checked the that both the file name and the path are legit and correct. Could someone please guide me what's wrong? Was it the syntax of the code? If so, could someone please guide me as im not familiar with subprocess syntax.

```
subprocess.call(['"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/bin/Rscript.exe"', '"C:/Cygwinx64/home/vettra/Python Play Zone/test2.R"'] , executable='"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/bin/Rscript.exe"')
```

Comment: Your strings have two pairs of quotes. Drop one of them.

Comment: Hi Aran, dropping the ' ' will result in the error ` 'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command"` instead. 

I tried dropping the line `executable="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/bin/Rscript.exe" ` but it generates yet another set of error :
`PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`

Comment: 1) [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) doesn't even *take* a `executable` argument. (To be accurate, it silently ignores it.) So I very much doubt that removing it produces a different kind of error. 2) There's no way the code you posted produces a `'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command"` error. You're probably passing `shell=True` to `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Hi Aran, 
I tried the following :
`subprocess.call(["C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/bin/Rscript.exe", "C:/Cygwinx64/home/vettra/Python Play Zone/test2.R"])`

This was thrown:
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Tested the following as well:
`subprocess.call(['"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/bin/Rscript.exe"', '"C:/Cygwinx64/home/ztoh/Pyhton Play Zone/test2.R"'])`

This was thrown:
`PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied`

Comment: Sorry but I don't believe that. I can't test it for myself because I'm on linux, but I'm 99% sure that line of code can't possibly throw that exception.

Comment: Hi Aran, thanks for looking into it. Im not lying either :\ Is there anyway i can post a screenshot?